# How do I make AJAX grab the data from the controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, umbraco

So, I have this AJAX call and what I want to do is for the controller to return the string as a JSON object back to the view where my ajax call is. Now here's the thing. I don't know how to do it and which class would help me do it. Everything I've tried doesn't work at all. My question is when I use the $.post method how do I make AJAX "grab" the data back from the controller?

Since people comment on my Javascript, I don't mind that, I'll fix it later. The question is

### How do I return anything I want from the controller in MVC? The controller is where I need help

Here's my call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("document ready");

            // Attach a submit handler to the form
        $("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
            alert("submitsearchForm");
                //event.preventDefault();

                // Get some values from elements on the page:
                var $form = $(this),
                query2 = $form.find("input[id='query']").val(),
                url = "/umbraco/Surface/SearchDictionarySurface/HandleDictionarySearching/";

                alert("query2" + query2);

                // Send the data using post
                var posting = $.post(url, { query: query2 });

                alert(url);

                //Put the results in a div
                posting.done(function (query2) {
                    var content = //bla bla bla;
                    $("#result").empty().append(content);
                    alert(query2);
                });

            });
        });    
</script>
```

Also, I'm using Umbraco. That's why the surface controller:

```
using MyUmbraco.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyUmbraco.Controllers
{
    public class SearchDictionarySurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        // GET: SearchDictionarySurface
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult HandleDictionarySearching(string query)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {

                var query2 = Json.parse(query);

                //return Json object????
                //I NEED HELP HERE
            }

            else
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know your framework, but for Ajax to receive response you have to output Json instead of returning it.

Comment: What you are trying to do with this statement `$(query2).find("#content")`?. `query2` is your response in Json format?

Comment: Guys, I've mentioned it before. Ignore this part, I'll fix this later, what I need help is to set up the controller. It's just a test, that line of code, so I would say. 'I have no clue as of now, because I haven't reached that point'.

Comment: @Justinas how do I do that in the controller? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Does your post return anything at all? E.g when it alerts query2 as part of the done call, what does it say? In your chrome inspector, in network, does the call to the post return a 200, or another status?

Comment: No, that's not the error but I found out how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to any newbies out there that might need the help I needed (and because I've been looking for this thing for AGES and nobody responds, here's how you do it:

Your JQuery callback function, and your controller must have the same variable. E.g:

Controller:

```
public JsonResult ExampleName(string query)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {

                //YOUR CODE HERE
               return Json(yourDataHere);
            }

            else
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home"),
                    isRedirect = true
                });
            }
        }
```

And JQuery callback function:

```
posting.done(function (data) {
                  //your callback function here
                   });
```

That's the trick for JQuery to know what to "grab" from the controller when it returns it. Make sure you return Json(yourDataHere). In case you're wondering, yes, just write 'data' in the function and it will grab yourDataHere from the controller, by itself.

Also, make sure you either have the AntiForgeryToken in both your form and your controller or in none of them. If you have it in your controller only, it will not let you control everything through JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issues in your javascript.

Try to follow this pattern :

```
posting.done(function (response) {
    var JSONData = JSON.parse(response);
    // do something with your json
    // ....
    // Then append your results in your div.
    $('YOUR DIV SELECTOR').html(THAT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY);
});
```

Comment: How is it an issue in my javascript when it's an exact copy from the JQuery documentation?

Edit: That sounded a bit offensive, I didn't mean it that way. I mean my problem is not even there. I can't set up the controller to return anything. That's what I need help on. I will figure the rest out on my own. Appreciate the help a lot though. Could you explain what the JSON.parse(response); would do in this case?

Comment: Send me the link ^^

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Ok I see, in this example the return of Jquery post is html, so they parsed html, not a JSON ;) don't follow this example for your use case ;)
Btw I don't know Umbraco but the doc say to return something like this : `return Json(YOUR DATA, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowPost);`

Comment: So if I return the query from the user (where you have placed YOUR DATA) then the callback function will grab it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return objects and JSON, use a WebAPI controller rather than a surface controller, which will just return an ActionResult. You can get a Surface controller to return JSON, but you'd be better off using an API controller, as that will return JSON objects by default, which is what I assume you're after?

[Here's some documentation for WebAPI controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/)!

Comment: Thank you for the link, I've seen the debate of API controllers vs Surface especially on Our.Umbraco forums and it's a matter of preference. Since I've set up everything already with Surface I'd like to go with it. Also, your post doesn't answer my question. I appreciate the effort, though.